# Weird behaviour of jodatime in parsing some date formats

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I was trying to parse a date string using jodatime with a leading '+' before the `yyyy` part. I expected an error to be thrown, but it actually did not throw an error. I got outputs that don't make any sense instead:

```
System.out.println(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd").parseDateTime("20130101"));
// 2013-01-01T00:00:00.000+05:30 (Expected) (case 1)

System.out.println(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd").parseDateTime("+20130101"));
// 20130-10-01T00:00:00.000+05:30 (??? Notice that month changed to 10 also) (case 2)

System.out.println(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MMyyyydd").parseDateTime("01+201301"));
// 20130-01-01T00:00:00.000+05:30 (??? At least month is fine this time) (case 3)

System.out.println(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM-yyyy-dd").parseDateTime("01-+2013-01"));
// 2013-01-01T00:00:00.000+05:30 (I expected an error, but this parsed correctly) (case 4)
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening? I expect either an exception, which means '+' sign is disallowed, or it should interpret +2013 as simply 2013, which is what it seems to do in the last case. But what is the deal with 20130 in case 2 and 3, and month = 10 in case 2?

Comment: `Integer.parseInt()` skips `+` at the beginning of the number but I'd expect `201-30-01` as result if it was related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through joda-time code, I was able to narrow down the issue. It was being caused due to an anomalous increment in the code. I have opened an issue [here](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/issues/86). I also have a fix ready [here](https://github.com/hshankar/joda-time/commit/4d7255901c897a8573e1a75c9e6927103de20ba2). I'll raise a pull request once I get confirmation on is it is the right way to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want throw exception on `+` sign you can use [DateTimeFormatterBuilder](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html), it is more flexible.
E.g. for format **yyyyMMdd**

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
         .appendFixedDecimal(DateTimeFieldType.year(), 4)
         .appendMonthOfYear(2)
         .appendDayOfMonth(2)
         .toFormatter();
dtf.parseDateTime("19990101");  - parsed correctly  
dtf.parseDateTime("-19990101"); - throw exception  
dtf.parseDateTime("+19990101"); - throw exception
```

also this pattern already present in standart patterns:

[ISODateTimeFormat::basicDate()](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#basicDate%28%29)

**EDIT**
But there is strange behaviour in case of using [appendFixedSignedDecimal](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendFixedSignedDecimal%28org.joda.time.DateTimeFieldType,%20int%29) method:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
         .appendFixedSignedDecimal(DateTimeFieldType.year(), 4)
         .appendMonthOfYear(2)
         .appendDayOfMonth(2)
         .toFormatter();
dtf.parseDateTime("19990101");  - parsed correctly  
dtf.parseDateTime("-19990101"); - parsed correctly   (negative years)  
dtf.parseDateTime("+19990101"); - throw exception (???)
```

I think this is issue in Joda lib, because

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
         .appendFixedSignedDecimal(DateTimeFieldType.year(), 4)
         .toFormatter();
```

works as expected

```
dtf.parseDateTime("1999");  - parsed correctly  
dtf.parseDateTime("-1999"); - parsed correctly (negative years)  
dtf.parseDateTime("+1999"); - parsed correctly
```

(This case is present in [Unit Tests](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/blob/master/src/test/java/org/joda/time/format/TestDateTimeFormatterBuilder.java#L305) for joda library)

Comment: This pointed me to the right part of the code. I was able to find and fix this issue. Not sure if it is the right fix, but I have opened an issue with the fix here - https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/issues/86. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this is not an answer, but could help..:

```
    Case 1:        2013-01-01T00:00:00.000-05:00
    Case 2:        20130-10-01T00:00:00.000-04:00
    Case 3:        20130-01-01T00:00:00.000-05:00
    Case 4:        2013-01-01T00:00:00.000-05:00
```

Note how case 2 changed timezones.

I'm in ET timezone and using joda-time v2.3